# Add HTML code in Javascript dropdown, Javascript dosen't evaluate HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use X-editable framework for my tables.

But i have some issues.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.access').editable({
        source: [
            {value: '0', text: 'Invalid'},
            {value: '1', text: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>'}
        ],
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: "json" //assuming json response
        },
        showbuttons: false
    });
});
```

I want to use the select dropdown with icons from font awesome.
But when i write the above code it just print `'<i class="fa fa-check"></i>'`

How can i evaluate that HTML code to display the icon?

I tried `document.write('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>')` but it delete the hole page.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is follow the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

To correctly create a node and `append` it to the place in the document you want it to appear.